# Деактивация/Активация камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Предположим, что у меня есть 2 камеры в разных позициях. Как реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку №1 - камера №1 отключалась и вместо неё была активна камера №2 и наоборот. При нажатии на кнопку №2 - камера №2 отключалась и вместо неё была активна камера №1.

p.s. как бонусом будет интересно, если это реализовано не через кнопки, а через перетаскиваемый бегунок.

Comment: через кнопки какие? OnGUI или UI ? или клавиатурные? или еще какие?

Comment: Интересен стандартный UI и NGUI.

p.s. возможно я не осознаю всех понятий)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У камеры есть свойство `enabled`, поменяв которое можно включить или выключить камеру. Остается только это знание применить в скрипте.

Если через UI, то у кнопок можно назначить событие `OnClick`.

Добавим две кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В их свойствах находим `OnClick`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем нужно выбрать объект, на котором висит скрипт-обработчик, а затем в правой части этого обработчика выбрать тот самый метод, который будет обрабатывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё. Готово.

Сам скрипт выглядит так:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchCameras : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam1;
    public Camera cam2;    

    private void Start() {
        cam1.enabled = true;
        cam2.enabled = false;
    }

    public void Switch() {
        cam1.enabled = !cam1.enabled;
        cam2.enabled = !cam2.enabled;
    }
}
```

Где в `cam1` и `cam2` назначена камера1 и камера2 соответсвенно. И где каждая из камер меняет свойство `enabled` на противоположное тому, что у него было.

---

Также можно с камерами поступать как с обычными объектами, которые можно делать активными или неактивными через [SetActive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)

то есть для включения камеры надо будет написать что-то типа

```
cam1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Например в том же скрипте мы можем определить метод с параметром

```
 public void Switch(int numCameraToOn)
```

который на вход будет принимать номер камеры, которую надо включить. Остальные - выключить.

При появлении метода с аргументами - в событии `OnClick` кнопки можно будет добавить этот самый параметр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у одной кнопки аргументом ставим например цифру 1,  другой кнопки - 2.

При нажатии одной из кнопок включаем одну камеру, выключаем другую через `SetActive`

Comment: А что если кнопки в одной сцене, а камеры в другой?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer тогда действия с кнопками бессмысленно)) Но вообще поясните пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду......Есть такой вид объектов как синглтоны и DontDestroyOnLoad.....их можно таскать со сцены на другую сцену, может оно вам надо?

Comment: Обидно) К примеру у меня есть сцена MainMenu,где есть меню опций. В меню опций 2 кнопки. (о которых говорилось в вопросе). Одна включает 1 камеру, другая 2 камеру. Но камеры находятся в сцене Game. ( По сути кнопки должны менять вид с вида сверху на вид от 3-го лица).

Comment: @ArtikSlayer вы можете из меню опций менять конфиги, а при загрузке сцены Game устанавливать камеру в нужное место. В момент, когда показывается меню опций, Game скорее всего не существует как объект в памяти.

Comment: Угу, спасибо. Уже придумал как сделать.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer кстати, выходить в меню, настраивать бегунком камеру и возвращаться в игру чтобы проверить результат - это наверняка очень неудобно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin в голове это выглядело так, что бегунок может быть в 2 позициях. Либо максимум влево либо максимум вправо. Влево - вид сверху, вправо - вид от третьего лица. То есть не было задумки зумить камеру относительно бегунка. Это действительно вызывает дискомфорт)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer как написал @Nick Volynkin - тогда можно все писать в конфиг.. а при старте игры две камеры должны быть выключены и лишь одну найти через `Find` , включить её и применить к ней настройки.... если переключение планируется производить н̶е̶ ̶о̶т̶х̶о̶д̶я̶ ̶о̶т̶ ̶к̶а̶с̶с̶ы̶ непосредственно в игре туда-сюда, то как раз таки можно с собой таскать некий игровой менеджер, в котором различные настройки....и  в скрипте кстати тогда вместо того чтобы пихать камеры в поля `Camera cam1;
    Camera cam2;` в методе `Start` тогда надо их будет просто найти. а потом скриптом менять по усмотрению

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я к кнопкам привязал методы, в которых хранятся значение переменной и через if проверяю. Если значение = 1 (кнопка 1), то через SetActive -  первая камера тру, вторая фолс, и наоборот, если значение = 2 (кнопка 2), то 1 камера фолс, 2 камера тру. =D

Comment: @ArtikSlayer ну подходы разные могут быть. Просто я не знал, что у вас все в разных сценах, а то ответ был б другим.....но в целом все равно сводится к тому, что при нажатии на кнопку вызывается какой-либо метод в каком либо связанном объекте,

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не переживайте. Это уже мои недочёты.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer кстати, имея конфиг, можно сделать еще проще. Вам не нужно две камеры вообще. Вы просто применяете конкретные настройки для одной единственной камеры, в зависимости от типа игры 2D/3D и все (не забывая у камеры менять ortographic на perspective и наоборот).. это просто как ход.... я вот некоторые конфиги храню в `*.asset`, например `GameData`, делаю кастомный `EditorWindow` для того, чтоб настроить параметры и всё. имхо удобно.