# Как скрыть ui объекты в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Перепробовал кучу скриптов, не одна не подошла. 
У меня есть ui button и при клике на него должна сработать следующее.

`layout.gameObject.SetActive(false);`

Но все, что я пробовал делал из интернета либо не работает, либо сразу пропадает без нажатие на кнопки. Как быть? Скрипт к кнопке привязал. layout к объекту тоже привязал, box collider 2d тоже сделал (увидел в каком то уроке).

Это последнее что я пробовал:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Button_close : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject layout; // Assign in inspector

    void OnGUI()
    {
        layout.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Скрины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привязка к кнопке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выложи код в котором сразу пропадает без нажатия

Comment: Обновил. с этим кодом сразу пропадает

Comment: @Mr.Husky `OnGUI` - это не для ui button, а для старого GUI........  и у тебя там явно нет кода, который сказал бы, что надо выполнить код "при нажатии на кнопку"

Comment: покажи скрин привязки кнопки к...... к чему ты там и что привязывал)

Comment: да я вот думаю в этом то и проблема. Делал через onmouseup и down тоже беда)

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/b1566b4f49ac4f148b8bd77f475fa62f.png

Comment: box collider 2d тоже сделал. увидел в каком то уроке xD

Comment: Что-то я не вижу привязку к ui button ........ зайди сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542492/191482 посмотри как это делается

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/d02185858d494a68b79be3535aecdb40.png

Comment: Все верно ведь?

Answer (score 2):

В целом сделано почти верно...но `box collider 2d` на ui кнопке точно не нужен.

В свойстве кнопке `OnClick` нужно не просто добавить объект на котором висит скрипт-обработчик, а нужно в правой части этого обработчика выбрать тот самый метод, который будет обрабатывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом важно, чтобы метод находился в том самом скрипте, который обработает событие, а также, чтобы этот метод был **публичным**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Button_close: MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject layout;

    public void Close() {
        layout.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

---

Метод `OnGUI` предназначен для рисования GUI элементов и он тут вообще не нужен

---

**P.S.** Т.к. в данном случае управление закрытием выглядит странно: единственный скрипт с названием `Button_close` с одним методом `Close`, то в дальнейшем стоит сделать какой-либо объект с управляющим скриптом, например `UI_Manager`, в котором будут определены методы по управлению `UI`

Comment: @Mr.Husky замечу что т.к. в данном случае управление закрытием выглядит странно: единственный скрипт с названием `Button_close` с одним методом `Close`, то в дальнейшем стоит сделать какой-либо объект с управляющим скриптом, например `UI_Manager`, в котором будут определены методы по управлению `UI`

Comment: Ну хорошо, с ui_manager еще не знаком.

Comment: так `ui_manager` это Алексей имеет ввиду вы сами напишете, в нем сделаете скрипты которые сможете вызывать из кнопок или других контролов. Например вам надо чтобы при изменении поля с `IP` у вас вызывалось переподключение в сети, вы в `ui_manager` добавляете метод который по ссылке вызывает переподключение в `Network`, а в поле содержащим ссылку на `IP` в `UI поле` вы добавляете вызов через `ui_manager` этого метода.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Тут где пакеты Юнити, должен быть еще пакет с UI

using UnityEngine;

//Он позволит работу с элементами Ui

using UnityEngine.Ui;

//а потом там где нужно выключаем кнопку

button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```